# Simple SFTP script

Tags: python, ssh, sftp

I am getting error failed to load hostkeys.

Hello,

I'm having trouble with a script i wrote to push a file to an SFTP. I'm using windows and the below is the code I have so far. The actual data manipulation and naming change works fine - it breaks at the SFTP portion. I'm hoping one of you guru's out there can help a newbie out.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pysftp
import sys

today = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%m%d%y"))

report = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nickkeith2\\PycharmProjects\\clt\\041719_clt_Facility_company_Inv.csv')

report.columns = report.columns.str.replace('_', ' ')

report.to_csv('C:\\Users\\nickkeith2\\PycharmProjects\\clt\\' + today + '_clt_Facility_company_Inv2.csv',
              index=False)

remote_file = 'C:\\Users\\nickkeith2\\PycharmProjects\\clt\\' + today + '_clt_Facility_company_Inv2.csv'[1]

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.load("C:\\Users\\nickkeith2\\id_rsa.pub")

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", username="sftpuser")

srv.put(remote_file)

srv.close()

print(report.columns)
```

I have tried various of combinations of using a key, not using a key and using a password instead - but no matter what it returns the error:

```
UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\nickkeith2\.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
  warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
```

I tried to create the folder in windows it specifies to put the key there but it will not allow me too. Thank you in advance on any insight you may be able to provide.

Comment: A `id_rsa.pub` file is not a host key.

Comment: To be clear, the host keys file is used by the client to make sure the host it's connecting to is genuine (it's a list of the known public keys *identifying the remote servers*, not anything to do with the public keys *identifying the user* who's logging in).

Comment: Thank you - back to the drawing board.

Comment: Charles - after reading online i see to try :                                                        cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None - but this gives me the same error, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully complete this using paramiko instead of PYSFTP.

Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import paramiko


ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())


today = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%m%d%y"))

report = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nickkeith2\\PycharmProjects\\clt\\041719_marshall_Facility_clt_Inv.csv')

report.columns = report.columns.str.replace('_', ' ')

report.to_csv('C:\\Users\\nickkeith2\\PycharmProjects\\clt\\' + today + '_marshall_Facility_clt_Inv2.csv',
              index=False)

remote_file = 'C:\\Users\\nickkeith2\\PycharmProjects\\clt\\' + today + '_marshall_Facility_clt_Inv2.csv'

ssh_client.connect(hostname="xxxxxxxx", username="xxxxxxxx", password="xxxxxxxxxx")

ftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()
ftp_client.put(remote_file, '\\Outbound\\'+ today + '_marshall_Facility_clt_Inv2.csv')
ftp_client.close()

print(report.columns)
```

Comment: When actually putting the code into production its being rejected as the file not being found when trying to push it to the client's SFTP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Transcribing Charles Duffy's comments as an answer:

An `id_rsa.pub` file is not a host key. To be clear, the host keys file is used by the client to make sure the host it's connecting to is genuine (it's a list of the known public keys *identifying the remote servers*, not anything to do with the public keys *identifying the user who's logging in*).